# Populating a newly added column in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, populate, fill

I have added a new column **default** to a table named **property** in my database through a migration.

```
class AddDefaultToProperty < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :property, :is_default, :boolean
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :property, :is_default
  end
end
```

The **default** column contains a **boolean** value which says if the **property** is a default one or not. Now I need a way to populate that column for some specific rows. Which is the best way to do this task? The default properties will probably change in the near future so I need some flexible way to contemplate this situation.

**USING RAILS 2.3.10**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That depends.  If it's an integral part of the migration and you want that data to be available immediately after the migration completes, then you should put that script directly into your migration.  If the data availability can wait, you can also opt for creating a rake task to populate the data - the upside is that your migration will be faster and that the rake task is optional - the downside is that you have to run it manually.

Comment: Yes, data availability can wait. I think the second option will be more suitable. But how can I do that? The trivial solution I've thought was to find every row I need to be set as default and update the column with a 1. Is there another better aproach?

Comment: The fastest way is to use a MySQL command - since the updates will take place on the server rather than passing that information back to rails. For example, you can create a Rake task to execute the following SQL: "UPDATE property SET is_default = 1 WHERE some_attribute = true AND some_other_attribute = false".  If that's not an option, you can create a Ruby loop to update each of the records.

Answer (score 0):

I would recoment changing the data in the migration. This ensures that further migrations will always work as expected.

However, always ensure you create your own models for use within migrations, otherwise conflicats between newer models and older schemas will get you.

Just add this line the top of your migration:

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base; end
```

Comment: You can avoid the issue of newer models and older schemas by using the "reset_column_information" command within your migrations: Property.reset_column_information.  This will reset the schema information to the newest available schema and will avoid having to monkey-patch each of your models.

Comment: @pan I was talking more about things like validations on columns that don't exist, and the like. Although that is also a valid point.